# sqlite insertWithOnConflict returns -1 but I cannot see the error

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat

I want to know why my sqlite insertWithOnConflict returns -1. Is there a way to see the error that caused the -1?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can only surmised that the insert didn't occur. You might try filtering logcat with "sqlite" to see if anything is being reported, but that's only useful during development and not helpful at runtime.

Also, it's worth noting that the documentation for this method is incorrect. If you use `CONFLICT_IGNORE` and there is an existing row, this method returns `-1`, **not** the row ID of the existing row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertOrThrow()` instead to get an exception.